# Prevent multiple plots in RStudio's plot pane

Tags: r, plot, rstudio

I've currently got a function that loops, and with each loop, it plots some lines and the plot appears in RStudio's plot pane. What I've noticed is that every time the function loops and plots, it creates a brand new plot in the plot pane, so when the function has finished there's a multitude of plots stacked on top of each other in RStudio's plot pane. Is there any way to stop the build up of plots within RStudio? I still want the function to plot a new thing every loop (psuedo-animation), but I want to avoid the build up of plots.

I've tried calling `dev.off()` and `dev.new()` but this creates new windows that displays the plot, and I want to avoid this and keep the plot in RStudio's plot pane.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your function outputs a plot per loop, this is the expected behaviour within RStudio. Some solutions you might consider:

- assign each plot to a list element instead of outputting it, then deal with the list later
- output each plot to a file instead of to the RStudio pane
- if you really want animation (adding items to the same plot), look at [`gganimate`](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
par(mfrow=c(1,2))
```

Let me know if it was you need.